# Difference between AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and AutomaticKeepAlive in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Need the difference between AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin and AutomaticKeepAlive, went through the docs but didn't get much clarity on them.

Need an example on it.

```
  AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin
  AutomaticKeepAlive
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `AutomaticKeepAliveScreen`? Ther's no such class/widget. Do you mean https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAlive-class.html

Comment: yes, it is AutomaticKeepAlive only
thanks